# How do I detect mobile devices in blazor server side application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to detect if the user of my blazor server side application is using a mobile device. Is there any way to find out which device the user is using?

I know I can do it with a JSRuntime but is there any way to figure it out with pure C#?

Comment: just curious - why? what are you needing to change?

Comment: I want to assign a diffent parallax background image to my theme. Unfortunately my theme assigns the image to the data-parallax-bg attribute. In PHP I used the Mobile_Detect class.

Comment: why not use a media query for your css?

Comment: Because the theme needs the image inline. See: 
<section id="page-title" data-bg-parallax="<?php echo $parallax_image; ?>">

Comment: what theme? what framework is that?

Comment: It is just an HTML5 theme. https://themeforest.net/item/polo-responsive-multipurpose-html5-template/13708923

Comment: its generally bad to do stuff like this with the user agent. feature detection and media queries are the best way to do it.

Comment: My reason is to render a different UI for the mobile user, because my app is by design optimized for desktop. It is a business app that shows a huge amount of data to workers. A mobile worker does completely different thing (but the database is the same) - so he doesn't need tables, just searching one thing by a number then present the results as pure text. Desktop: table (imagine Excel), Mobile: text (imagine Word). And it is also not question of UI alone, the users see DIFFERENT selection of data (workers do different tasks).

Comment: `@if (IsWorker) { <WorkerComponent /> }`

Answer (score 7):

You can detect the user agent on the JavaScript side of your app, and reference that from the C# side.

Keep in mind that iPad browsers have some mobile features and some desktop features, so it is up to you how you want to handle iPad.

Here is a script taken from the Sycfusion website:

```
    [wwwroot/script.js]

function isDevice() {
    return /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini|mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

To include it in your app, you reference it in index.html

```
[index.html/_Host.cshtml]

<head>
 .....
 <script src="~/script.js"></script>
 ....
</head>
```

and then you invoke it in you blazor code

```
[index.razor]

@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<h1>Responsive</h1>

<button @onclick="FindResponsiveness">Find Device</button>
<h2>@isDevice</h2>
@code {
    private string isDevice { get; set; }
    private bool mobile { get; set; }
    public async Task FindResponsiveness()
    {
        mobile = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice");
        isDevice = mobile ? "Mobile" : "Desktop";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I did find this article that will read you the width and height of a window in Blazor. Looks like it uses JS Interop. With that, you can determine if a user is using a mobile based on the width of their resolution. Of course, it's not 100% full proof as someone on a desktop can resize their window down to a mobile resolution.
https://blazor.tips/blazor-how-to-ready-window-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Chris, but here is the link to the article where the code is from:

[Syncfusion mobile detection article](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/javascript-interop/how-do-you-detect-whether-a-page-is-loaded-in-mobile-or-on-desktop#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20find%20out%2C%20add%20a%20%E2%80%9Cscript.js%E2%80%9D,the%20isDevice%20method%20to%20identify%20the%20correct%20device.)

Included on this page is also a link to a site where this method has been implemented to help you test if this works for your specific use case and device:

[Mobile browser detection](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor Server (SSR) the best way I found is by accessing the HttpContext.

First we inject the httpContext

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
```

and then we can check in `OnInitializedAsync`

```
var userAgent = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
if (userAgent != null && (userAgent.Contains("Android") || userAgent.Contains("iPhone")))
{
    IsMobile = true;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` must be avoided with interactive rendering because there isn't a valid HttpContext available. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor

Comment: Yes, but thinking that it is a statically rendered root component. I don't see the problem with capturing the value in a root component and passing IsMobile as a parameter

Comment: Since the original question was seeking pure C# solution, answer of @EduardoPino is appropriate.