# Blazor Show Component only if on Mobile

Tags: blazor, .net-5

I have 2 components, one that I wish to display if the browser is Mobile, the other if it is tablet/desktop.

```
@if(isMobile)
{
   <MobileComponent />
}
else
{
   <DesktopComponent />
}
```

I am looking to not have the Mobile Component in the DOM at all when on desktop and vice versa so i dont want to do a CSS visibility. Id rather only the one be rendered.  What is the best approach to determine if the browser is a Mobile browser so I can set isMobile accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method that I created.  Add js to your Index.html page with the following function

```
<script>

    function isDevice() {
        return /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini|mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }

</script>
```

Then on any component where you want to know if the browser is mobile add the following

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    IsMobile = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice");
}
```

If you are using Chrome to debug, when you set the browser to mobile the value will be true

Answer (score 0):

If you have the above code in the Razor markup for the page/component, `<MobileComponent />` will only be rendered and therefore appear in the Dom when `ismobile` is true.  And visa versa of course.

In Blazor you don't need to screw around with css visibility, code it like you have. A huge amount of javascript css manipulation code just ain't needed anymore.

Comment: Im aware of that.  The question was more in regards to how to determine isMobile.  What is the best way of acquiring if the browser is a mobile browser so i can set isMobile correctly

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear.  try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270247/how-do-i-detect-mobile-devices-in-blazor-server-side-application)