# With ASP.NET Blazor and Blazorise, how do I use that to show content only on mobile?

Tags: xaml, blazor, blazorise

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105624/blazor-show-component-only-if-on-mobile) w/o an answer I like....
and since the following allows me to show the contents of Container only on desktopy env.

```
    <Container Display="Display.None.Block.OnFullHD">
        <AppHelpMenu />
    </Container>
```

How do I use that to show a Container only on mobile?

```
    <Container Display="Display.None.Block.Mobile">
        <AppHelpMenu />
    </Container>
```

That doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
<Container Display="Display.None.OnFullHD.None.OnTablet.Block.OnMobile">
    <NavHelp />
</Container>
```

First, you define how to show it (`None`), and then where to show it (`OnMobile`).

Comment: I edited your answer with what worked for me, but the description of HOW it works is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS works good enough

```
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .show-mobile-only {
        /* don't show on mobile */
        display: none;
    }
```

```
<div class="show-mobile-only" >
    <NavHelp />
</div>
```

Comment: Though I find something w/ working w/ Display.Blah would be cleaner and blazorising.