# How can I get the client browser User Agent from the JSRuntime in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to get the client side browser UserAgent in my Blazor server app. [There is this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270247/how-do-i-detect-mobile-devices-in-blazor-server-side-application) to test for mobile devices. But I want to get the agent to log the value, and then make a couple of decisions based on what the client is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (!firstRender)
        return;

    var str = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("eval", "navigator.userAgent");
}
```

And at the time of writing this, I am determining it is an Apple device if any of these strings are in the returned string.

```
private static string[] appleUserAgents = { "iphone", "ipad", "macintosh", "mac os x", "safari" };
```